# How is the suggestion result order when I use the solr spellcheck component?

Tags: search, solr, lucene

When I use the spellcheck component in Solr 4.6 and I get more then one result in the suggestion list, what is the order of these results?

Example (german):
searching for "deutch"

result:

..."spellcheck": {
    "suggestions": [
      "deutch",
      {
        "numFound": 5,
        "startOffset": 0,
        "endOffset": 6,
        "suggestion": [
          "deutsch",
          "dutch",
          "deutsche",
          "durch",
          "death"
        ]
      },
...

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, distance and popularity.

It calculates the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damerau%E2%80%93Levenshtein_distance), and sorts first by that, and then sorts within each group based on how frequently each possible replacement appears in the index.

- deutsch - distance: 1
- dutch - distance: 1
- deutsche - distance: 2
- durch - distance: 2
- death - distance: 2

Presumably "Deutsch" appears more often than  "dutch", and "deutsche" more often than "durch" or "death".